# Getting NoClassDefFoundError in below Lollipop

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 1.3. I have installed the latest SDK(**23**), After that I am getting some errors at the runtime **android.view.InflateException** and **NoClassDefFoundError**. These errors don't occur in Lollipop, but they do on Kitkat.

Before installing SDK 23 I didn't get any error on the Kitkat device.

**Now my build gradle is**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nanonino.notifeye"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        compileOptions {

            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':Materialtimepicker')
    compile project(':main')
    compile project(':library1')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
}
```

Error Log is

```
08-28 15:16:30.012  29750-29750/com.nanonino.notifeye E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nanonino.notifeye, PID: 29750
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nanonino.notifeye/com.nanonino.notifeye.signup_login.SignuporLoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #71: Error inflating class com.nanonino.notifeye.Utills.TypefacedTextViewrlight
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5077)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #71: Error inflating class com.nanonino.notifeye.Utills.TypefacedTextViewrlight
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1995)
            at com.nanonino.notifeye.signup_login.SignuporLoginActivity.onCreate(SignuporLoginActivity.java:86)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5395)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5077)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

**Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?**

This is my **TypefacedTextViewrlight.java**

```
package com.nanonino.notifeye.Utills;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TypefacedTextViewrlight extends TextView {

    public TypefacedTextViewrlight(Context context) {
        super(context);
        style(context);
    }

    public TypefacedTextViewrlight(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        style(context);
    }

    public TypefacedTextViewrlight(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        style(context);
    }

    private void style(Context context) {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "Roboto-Light.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }

}
```

Below is my xml file (**activity_signuporlogin.xml**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Takeatour"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TAKE A TOUR"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#78B452"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSignup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Takeatour"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blackbackgroundbutton"
            android:text="START YOUR 30-DAY FREE TRIAL"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnSignup"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B3B3B3" />

            <com.nanonino.notifeye.Utills.TypefacedTextViewrlight
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="  OR  "
                android:textColor="#808080" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B3B3B3" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/subscribe"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/orangebackgroundbutton"
            android:text="SUBSCRIBE NOW"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/txtLogin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/subscribe"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/emailbuttonpressed"
            android:text="ALREADY REGISTERED? LOG IN"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In your xml file at line number 71 you are using this com.nanonino.notifeye.Utills.TypefacedTextViewrlight. The problem is with view. Can you post your xml file?

Comment: Also can you post TypefacedTextViewrlight class file?

Comment: I have posted @SureshKumar

Comment: Usually the stack trace is a little bit longer, pointing out why the inflation of your view failed. May you check the console/logcat output again?

Comment: What I found that error happening from the class created from  my package name. If I call one class to another class this error occurring.  For example I called TypefacedTextViewrlight.java file into the xml. I got an error.If I call any Asynchronous task. I got the same error NoClassDefFoundError @ Capricorn

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: I didn't @abdul-rahman-k

Comment: What is in line no 86 in file SignuporLoginActivity.java?

Comment: Did you try to inflate any view type casting it to `TypefacedTextViewrlight` ?

Comment: This is line no 86 "setContentView(R.layout.activity_signuporlogin);"

Comment: I removed TypefacedTextViewrlight and then I have added normal TextView, After that error shows in asynchronous task class at run time. Error is NoClassDefFoundError. It's happened in below lollypop version only.If I call any class as object then I got error.

Comment: @MathaN  sorry for the later reply ,1.check the export and import tab in build path, 2. Check the bin folder of your project if the class files are found, if not then delete the bin folder and, clean and build the project once again

Comment: Ok, I will try it thank you :)

Comment: Did that solve your problem?